# Using Pandas fillna method so that the inserted values satisfy certain conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data =np.array([[1,3],
                                  [np.nan,5],
                                  [2,np.nan],
                                 [np.nan,np.nan],
                                 [4,7]]),
                  columns=['a','b'])


    a   b
0   1.0 3.0
1   NaN 5.0
2   2.0 NaN
3   NaN NaN
4   4.0 7.0
```

I have also computed the variance of each column a,b

```
vars_df = df.var(axis=0)

a    2.333333
b    4.000000
```

as well as the mean :

```
mean_df = df.mean(axis=0)

a    2.333333
b    5.000000
```

What I want to achieve is to fill the np.nan values under two conditions:

1. The mean of the inserted values per column be equal to mean of the initial values.
2. Follow the same logic as condition 1 but this time for the variance.

Notice that I don't want to fill the NaN values with the mean or the variance of the column although that will work for the mean. Ultimately what I want is that the NaN values combined have the same mean and variance with the remaining values of the column.

e.g for the variance

for `column a`

`var(1.0,2.0,4.0)=var(NaN_row1,NaN_row3)`

for `column b`

`var(3.0,5.0,7.0)=var(NaN_row2,NaN_row3)`

Is there a way to do so using the df.fillna() method?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
```

[image]

```
df.fillna(df.var())
```

Comment: Thanks @Ehtisham for your reply. That works great for the mean but not for the variance. I do not want to replace the NaN values with the mean or the variance of the column. I want the NaN values combined to have the same mean and the same variance with the rest of the column elements respectively.

Comment: Notice that my example is not really accurate so I will update it.Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: In column b for example I want `var(NaN_row2,NaN_row3)=4` and `mean(NaN_row2,NaN_row3)=5`

Comment: add expected output in your question. I didn't get your Question.

Comment: I did thanks for your remark! It was my mistake